# Is it bad to do Inner assignments?

Tags: java, coding-style

We were having this discussion wiht my colleagues about Inner assignments such as:

```
return result = myObject.doSomething();
```

or

```
if ( null == (point = field.getPoint()) )
```

Are these acceptable or should they be replaced by the following and why?

```
int result = myObject.doSomething();
return result;
```

or

```
Point point = field.getPoint();
if ( null == point)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `result` in the first case is a member of a class rather than a local variable. Otherwise, the assignment is redundant.

Comment: @nhahtdh redundant maybe but the code is clearer and this was our discussion clearer code or more concise?

Comment: I know, but since you brought up the replacement, I just had to comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The inner assignment is harder to read and easier to miss. In a complex condition it can even be missed, and can cause error.

Eg. this will be a hard to find error, if the condition evaluation prevent to assign a value to the variable:

```
if (i == 2 && null == (point = field.getPoint())) ...
```

If `i == 2` is false, the point variable will not have value later on.

Comment: Example attached, the point variable may not contain value if the condition is failed prematurely.

Comment: && and || is short-circuit evaluation, that means if i != 2, point=field.getPoint() will not be evaluated

Comment: I don't think this is a valid argument against inner assignments... if you write things badly that's not its fault. When considering if statements I agree it's not good, but in while statements, not using an inner assignment can lead to writing the same assignment twice, which is also not great.

Comment: The same stands for goto. It can be used right and can be used wrong, but generally considered a bad practise. It's not that extreme in this case, but better to be careful when using. I just highlighted the dangers.

Answer (score 8):

`if ( null == (point = field.getPoint()) )`

Pros:

- One less line of code

Cons:

- Less readable.
- Doesn't restrict `point`'s scope to the statement and its code block.
- Doesn't offer any performance improvements as far as I am aware
- Might not always be executed (when there is a condition preceding it that evaluates to false.

Cons outweigh pros 4 / 1 so I would avoid it.

Comment: Not saying that inner assignments are good, but regarding your answer I have to state the following:
1. if the inner assignment is the first operand, it also improves readability `if ( (point = field.getPoint()) == null )` I want to say with that: your example decreases the readability even more.
2. regarding "doesn't restrict `point`'s scope" --> that's what an inner assignment is supposed to do, so you could also write that as a pro and remove it from cons :)

Answer (score 6):

This is mainly concerned with readablity of the code. Avoid inner assignments to make your code readable as you will not get any improvements with inner assignments

Answer (score 5):

**Functionally** `Not Necessarily.`
**For Readability** `Definitely Yes`

Answer (score 5):

They should be avoided. Reducing the number of identifiers/operations per line will increase readability and improve internal code quality. Here's an interesting study on the topic: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1390647

So bottom line, splitting up

```
return result = myObject.doSomething();
```

into

```
result = myObject.doSomething();
return result;
```

will make it easier for others to understand and work with your code. At the same time, it wouldn't be the end of the world if there were a couple inner assignments sprinkled throughout your code base, so long as they're easily understandable within their context.

Comment: But why not use just `return myObject.doSomething();` in that case?

Comment: Yep, that's usually better. I would only do intermediate assignment when dealing with long / complex method chains. In those cases, the variable name can serve as documentation.

Comment: I like that way once, but Sonar complains about it - that's where I have this idea that is bad from.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first one is not exactly inner assignment but in second case...it reduces readability ...but in some cases like below,

```
while ( null == (point = field.getPoint()) );
```

it's good to write it this way

Answer (score 3):

In both cases the first form is harder to read, and will make you want to change it whenever you want to inspect the value in a debugger. I don't know how often I've cursed "concise" code when step-debugging.

Answer (score 3):

There are a very few cases where inner assignments reduce program complexity, for example in `if (x != null && y != null && ((c = f(x, y)) > 0) {...}` and you really only need the assignment in the case when it is executed in the complex condition.

But in most cases inner assignments reduce readability and they easily can be missed.

I think inner assignments are a relict to the first versions of the C programming language in the seventies, when the compilers didn't do any optimizations, and the work to optimize the code was left to the programmers. In that time inner assignments were faster, because it was not necessary to read the value again from the variable, but today with fast computers and optimizing compilers this point doesn't count any more. Nevertheless some C programmers were used to them. I think Sun introduced inner assignments to Java only because they wanted to be similar to C and make it easy for C programmers to change to Java.

Answer (score 2):

Always work and aim for code **readability** not **writeability**. The same goes for stuff like `a > b ? x : y;`
There are probably many developers out there not having issues reading your first code snipet but most of them are used to the second snipet.

Answer (score 2):

The more verbose form also makes it easier to follow in a Debugger such as Eclipse. I often split up single line assignments so the intermediate values are more easily visible.

Although not directly requested by OP a similar case is function calls as method arguments may save lines but are harder to debug:

```
myFunction(funcA(), funcB());
```

does not show the return types and is harder to step through. It's also more error-prone if the two values are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any harm in using inner assignments. It saves few lines of code (though im sure it doesn't improve compiling or execution time or memory). The only drawback is that to someone else it might appear cumbersome.